# System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt returns null

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm trying to encrypt some userData to create my own custom IPrincipal and IIdentity objects using Forms authentication - I've serialized an object representing my logged in user to Json and created my FormsAuthentication ticket like so:

```
string user_item = GetJsonOfLoggedinUser();/*get JSON representation of my logged in user*/

System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = 
    new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
    WAM.Utilities.SessionHelper.LoggedInEmployee.F_NAME + " " 
    + WAM.Utilities.SessionHelper.LoggedInEmployee.L_NAME,
    DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, user_item);

string encrypted_ticket = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

HttpCookie auth_cookie = 
    new HttpCookie(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,        encrypted_ticket);

Response.Cookies.Add(auth_cookie);
```

However, the string `encrypted_ticket` is always `null`. Is there a limit on the length of the `user_item` string?

Thanks
Mustafa

Comment: For me, if the Name property on the ticket is null then the Encrypt function returns null.  The 4KB limit applies to the cookie and not to the encrypted value.  If the encrypted value is greater than 4KB, then the attempt to add a cookie will fail.

Comment: same problem with me  , but with mine @Mayo answer fixed it

Comment: Thanks @Mayo, your technique solved my problem, Alhamdulillah("All praise is due to Allah ([God] alone").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the typical cookie limit is ~4k.

Add encryption and you are down to <2k.

Your code is correct.. consider:

```
string user_item = "fsddfdfssdfsfdasdfsf";

System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
    new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
     " sdfasdf asdflasdfasd ",
    DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, user_item);

string encrypted_ticket = 
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

HttpCookie auth_cookie = 
    new HttpCookie(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted_ticket);
```

Yields:

```
95ED981CFDF6AE506650E2AD01D2B52666AFC4895F0E19F14D82628C3F263EF1DA77F73BFD0284BEDCF815FBFB9AF00AF8875C61D01E27BF53C229F19C7CDE54FBC10AC478FAF02237DDC545AEF32BBA8EED88DBB09D671CD87E685E9FE05908CAE02EB05880DC1D230D67AEB0D7B0F258435D906EBD7F505DCCD738D94532E96363B13DA92060720476619672FEC670
```

While it is my experience that bloated cookies are truncated as opposed to nulled, your issue is probably that JSON contains characters that will make your cookie malformed, thus breaking it.

Make sure your json is a reasonable size, then try

```
string user_item = Server.UrlEncode(GetJsonOfLoggedinUser());
```

Make sure you measure your cookies and don't try to push it, it will bite in subtle and vicious ways when you want to be home watching Lost and drinking tequila. no fun.

Comment: did you get Lost because you were drinking tequila?

Answer (score 34):

As an addition to this issue, when the *userData* parameter is `null` the *encrypted_ticket* will also be `null`.

In this example:

```
var ticket = new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
         "username",
        DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, null);

string encrypted_ticket = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
```

*encrypted_ticket* yields now `null`. However when using an empty string or `string.Empty` for the *userData* parameter we get a valid *encrypted_ticket*.

This is also somewhat documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kybcs83h.aspx)

> Note
>
> The userData parameter cannot be null.

Comment: Thanks for the details - wish an exception was thrown when userdata was null.

Comment: OMG Thank you. I have spent 2 hours trying to figure this out and getting nowhere.

Comment: @Mustafakidd Right - this is like the textbook example of when to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

i used this code to redirect from login page to may deafault.aspx page and my UserData was Null like your Problem:

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);

i change the code , try this code to redirect from Login.aspx to Default.aspx page and your User Data will be fine:

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(UserName, false));

....
```