# FormsAuthentication.Decrypt always returns null in one of the web servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a webform application based on asp.net 4.0, deployed to two different servers. The webform application has only one Default.aspx with its code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MachineKeySection section =
     (MachineKeySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/machineKey");

    this.Response.Write(section.DecryptionKey);
    this.Response.Write("<br />");

    this.Response.Write(section.ValidationKey);
    this.Response.Write("<br />");

    var authToken = "xxxxxx";  
        //the real token is obviously not xxx, just an example here

    this.Response.Write(authToken);
    this.Response.Write("<br />");

    var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authToken);
    if (ticket != null) this.Response.Write(ticket.Name);
    this.Response.End();
}
```

the same code with the same web.config is deployed to two web servers. However, one of them works fine, and another always has its `ticket` equals to null. If I remove `if (ticket != null)` then an null reference exception is thrown. They have totally the same output, except the ticket part.

The web servers are running on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, with .NET framework 4 installed. I'm sure the code on the two web servers are toally the same, including the machineKey:

```
<machineKey validationKey="xxx" decryptionKey="yyy" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

How can this happen? Do you have any idea about this weired issue?

**UPDATE**

MS BUG, need to update package: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2656351

Comment: Check Windows Update on both servers.  Can you verify that both servers are fully patched and that there are no outstanding updates?

Comment: @Levi: We've already checked all related updates are installed in both servers. Their system enviornments are almost the same.

Comment: How are you retrieving the `authToken`? If Decrypt returns a null value then it means that whatever you are passing is not valid. Otherwise you would receive an `ArgumentException`. I suspect it might be a problem with the `authToken` rather than the Decryption.

Comment: @Barry: Agree. But the auth token is valid for all other servers(with the same machine key as the issued server). So I think the auth token is ok.

Comment: Presumably you experience the issue in both directions? That is, auth token created on machine A won't decrypt on machine B, and a token created on machine B won't decrypt on machine A? Also, on each server, will a recycle of the app-pool cause a token to be invalidated? That is, create a token on machine A, recycle it's app-pool, then decrypt the token. Does it still work? If not, then it's not actually using the config values.

Comment: What about the lower level config files, like machine config, or the other global web config?   Are those the same?

Comment: @RodJohnson: They are the same.

Comment: Danny - Did you try my suggested tests? They may not reveal the answer, but they'll push the problem into smaller gaps of possibilities.

Comment: @Snixtor: Appreciate for your suggestion. But I left the project team last month, so I don't know what's going on now... sorry for that

Comment: Hey don't say sorry to me, say it to the guys that have been left with the problem :) You might actually consider deleting the question now that it's pretty much unanswerable though, due to your separation from the environment.

Comment: Please see this same issue in this site


http://stackoverflow.com/a/10726436/1193035

Comment: may check your authToken at the time of decryption may it take a blank space or any special char.

Comment: Is the auth cookie reaching the server? Is there any chance the auth cookie is marked as Secure (HTTPS) and you are accessing a non-HTTPS page?

Comment: @epignosisx: I'm sure all servers got the same correct cookie value, but they had a different decryption result.

Comment: can you please check the following url: http://www.altafkhatri.com/Technical/Configure/Common_ASP_NET/Machine_Config_Values_Not_Picking_up_Solution_Reso

Comment: I am voting to close as too broad. With you no longer on that team we are all taking guesses. It might be a silly thing that was missed when checking, it happens.

Comment: It might sound silly but are you using FormsAuthentication on both servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While employing load Balancers, I had ran into this exact issue as you mentioned. [ .net Framework 4.0 ]

All things were being verified so many times with NO success.

Just wanted to share the below link as finally the Security Update: [MS11-100](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2656351) had fixed the issue in my case.

Tony considers likely this to be bug in .net 4.0 http://tmoaikel.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/formsauthentication-decrypt-returns-null/ , which was fixed by the above patch.

May be this may help you progress little further.