# Mocking FormsAuthentication in MVC

Tags: c#, mocking, tdd, rhino-mocks

I have the code below and want to test the scenario when FormsAuthentication returns null.  How can I do this, using mocking I assume, since FormsAuthentication is a sealed class with static methods.  I am using RhinoMocks.

```
    public PaxiumPrincipal CreatePrincipalFromCookie(string cookieValue)
    {
        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookieValue);

        if (authTicket == null)
        {
            return null;
        };

        var userPrincipal = new PaxiumPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), null);

        return userPrincipal;
    }
```

Comment: Anant - a nice article on Forms Authentication but adds nothing at all to answering my question.  Did you read my question?

Comment: You could put a wrapper class around the FormsAuthentication class so that it can be mocked up. If this method broke in your app you would find out straight away (as soon as you login) so is creating a unit test for it worth it?

Comment: Creating a unit test is the only way if you are doing TDD as you write a test first and then write the code!

Comment: Also answering this question also answers other similar scenarios involving sealed classes and static methods.

Comment: Your answer is good though I think - post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I see no evidence FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() ever returns null, other than [a bug described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317129/formsauthentication-decrypt-always-returns-null-in-one-of-the-web-servers). Instead it throws an `ArgumentException` when the cookie is invalid. I think you should test that the cookie hasn't expired though..

But for the sake of argument, this is how you TDD a sealed class:

## Create an interface for all methods you need

This goes into your production code:

```
public interface IFormsAuthentication
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket Decrypt(string cookieValue);
}
```

## Create a wrapper around the sealed class

This also goes into your production code:

```
public class MyFormsAuthentication : IFormsAuthentication
{
    public FormsAuthenticationTicket Decrypt(string cookieValue)
    {
        return FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookieValue);
    }
}
```

## Change the method you want to test

It should use the `IFormsAuthentication` object it's provided with instead of the sealed class. In production this should be your wrapper.
Obviously this is in your production code...

```
public class PaxiumPricipalCreator
{
    IFormsAuthentication _formsAuthentication;
    public PaxiumPricipalCreator(IFormsAuthentication formsAuthentication)
    {
        _formsAuthentication = formsAuthentication;
    }

    public PaxiumPrincipal CreatePrincipalFromCookie(string cookieValue)
    {
        var authTicket = _formsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookieValue);

        if (authTicket == null)
        {
            return null;
        };

        var userPrincipal = new PaxiumPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), null);

        return userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

## Create a unit test with a mock authenticator (This example is in MSTest)

This is your TEST code:

```
[TestClass]
public class PaxiumPricipalCreatorTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Returns_NULL_principal_when_IFormsAuthentication_returns_null()
    {
        var mockAuthenticator = new NullReturningFormsAuthentication();
        var principalCreator = new PaxiumPricipalCreator(mockAuthenticator);

        var actual = principalCreator.CreatePrincipalFromCookie(string.Empty);

        Assert.IsNull(actual);
    }


    public class NullReturningFormsAuthentication : IFormsAuthentication
    {
        public FormsAuthenticationTicket Decrypt(string cookieValue)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```